# Which listener is called when we click on a combo box in SWT?

Tags: java, combobox, swt

Which listener is called when we click on combo box in SWT? I am making a calendar which will appear by clicking on combo box. How can I determine that a combo box has been clicked?

Comment: Since `Combo` uses a native control you may have problems stopping it from displaying the drop down list. Look at the `CCombo` class source to see what that does using a separate button control.

Comment: Dear I want to determine that whether the combo box has been clicked or not and based upon it I want to perform some action. My question is how can we determine that combo box has been clicked?

Comment: There is no way to tell when the `Combo` drop-down is clicked.

Comment: There is always a way :)

Comment: You can do it by using Default selection Listener and Focus Listener.

Comment: @Noor Then please post your solution as an answer.

Comment: @Noor Since SWT uses a native control which does not give any indication that the drop-down has been clicked there is no way to do this. You can see a selection being made but you cannot see the drop down click.

Answer (score 0):

Generally the component will check all registered listeners, so if you register something, it will be called.

You have docs for the component: [org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Combo](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fwidgets%2FCombo.html)

You have several listeners that you can register in base class org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control. You have also 3 specific for Combo: ModifyListener, SelectionListener and VerifyListener.

For your case it looks like, that you would have to implement and register ModifyListener and SelectionListener for cases, when user enters a date from a keyboard or selects it from a calendar and VerifyListener for validation purposes.

Comment: Dear I want to determine that whether the combo box has been clicked or not and based upon it I want to perform some action. My question is how can we determine that combo box has been clicked?

Comment: But does registering listener and implementing action there won't work for your case?

Comment: You can do it by using Default selection Listener and Focus Listener.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using Default selection Listener and Focus Listener. Focus listener is for mouse events and default selection listener for key pressed by keyboard.

Comment: `FocusListener` will also fire if you tab through your controls. Is that what you want?